# What does "Whitelabel" mean in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration in Spring Boot provides a default error page, "Whitelabel Error Page". But I don't understand what does the whitelabel mean.

What is "whitelabel"? Is it a famous imaginary product in the Spring community?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_label

Comment: called as whitelable because you can and need to customize it